# Androidplot: Improve Axis layout (remove cutoff values)

Tags: android, graph, charts, androidplot

On Androidplot my Axis Vals are cut off, so the last values are only shown half.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setMarginTop(4);
dynamicPlot.getLegendWidget().setHeight(14);
```

Luckly I still found something in the androidplot forums cache.

Answer (score 6):

In case the solution by Coretek doesn't work for you, as it did not for me, I found this solution to produce the desired output:

```
YOURPLOT.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingRight(AmountOfSpaceDesired);
YOURPLOT.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingTop(AmountOfSpaceDesired);
```

This will not just move your axis to no longer be cut off, but also your graph. I wanted a little extra space on the top where I previously had a point touching along with the right side where another point was touching.

I hope this can help someone as it has helped me.

Comment: Note that if your range values (vertical left axis) are cut off, all you have to do is `plot.getGraphWidget().setPaddingLeft(15);`